# Could not find (Package name). Searched in the following locations:

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, gradle-plugin

When I try to build my Android project, I'm facing this issue:
`

```
1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugAarMetadata'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':app:debugRuntimeClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.github.corouteam:GlideToVectorYou:v2.0.0.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/github/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou/v2.0.0/GlideToVectorYou-v2.0.0.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/github/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou/v2.0.0/GlideToVectorYou-v2.0.0.pom
       - https://jitpack.io/com/github/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou/v2.0.0/GlideToVectorYou-v2.0.0.pom
     Required by:
         project :app
```

`

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i5VKT.png)

How can I solve the issue by downloading the package above?

Previously, it was working fine. However, When I try downgrade the version number to 1.2.0. It's working fine. Thus, the issue seems with version 2.0.0.

Comment: Have you added `jitpack` as instructed in the github repo? https://github.com/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou#how-to-use

Comment: @Javlon Yes, already. But still face the same issue.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The artifact host has been changed to `https://jitpack.io/#2coffees1team/GlideToVectorYou`.
Replace

```
com.github.corouteam:GlideToVectorYou:v2.0.0
```

to

```
com.github.2coffees1team:GlideToVectorYou:v2.0.0
```

Credits: https://github.com/corouteam/GlideToVectorYou/issues/18#issuecomment-1324610503

Comment: Thanks for the fix. This annoying change on GitHub was confusing and broke our build.

Comment: Currently this new link doesn't work either...

Comment: This does work, just needed to add maven { url "https://jitpack.io" } to settings.gradle